# Change array element value to previous one +1

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [start] => 2015-02-01 
        [end] => 2015-02-28 
        [type_FK] => Compensation 
        [employee_FK] => 0 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [start] => 2015-02-19 
        [end] => 2015-02-26 
        [type_FK] => Paid Vacation 
        [employee_FK] => 0 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [start] => 2015-02-20 
        [end] => 2015-02-12 
        [type_FK] => Study 
        [employee_FK] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

The important part is the `[employee_FK] => 0` . If I delete an employee the order will be messed up in my PHP generated HTML table, because I need the employee_FK to determine in which row it has to be entered in my table (0, 2 instead of 0, 1).

How can I change all the FKs to the previous ones +1?

For example if the order is 0, 3, 7 it should be 0, 1, 2.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: I don't see any pattern behind this and don't get it what your want! What would be the expected output of this array here?

Comment: I have a table where I print the leaves of employees. However, I use the FK of an employee to find out the correct row and the day of the absence for the column. For example: if the absence is on the 25th of the month and the employee_FK of that absence is 1, it goes in the second row and column 25. The problem is when an employee gets deleted, then someone else gets the absences of that person.